# how to install Windows 8.1 on UEFI boot mode

Tags: windows-8.1, uefi

I have a dell 5559 lap top. It has Ubuntu but I want to install Windows 8.1 on it.

UEFI mode does not recognize bootable pen drive.

I disable that secure boot mode but same error occurred.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You shouldn't disable Secure Boot.  Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 both support it. Does your Windows 8.1 installation .ISO have the appropriate EFI drivers on it?

Comment: EFI needs to recognise the filesystem on which the load is installed so it can search for the right files on this. The only filesystem which is guaranteed to work is (not accidentally) 100% compatible with FAT32. Check if the pendrive is formatted with that or with NTFS? If NTFS reformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a USB drive to load Windows installation, try something like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

When creating a bootable drive, load a bootable Windows DVD with UEFI support and select *GPT ... UEFI* and *NTFS* as formatting parameters. You should see at least two partitions on your USB drive after installer creation is done, one is a normal NTFS partition with **Windows installation file** and another one called **UEFI_NTFS**.